# limit job authorization scope does not allow fetch in spite of manually added permission

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

we use yaml pipelines in azure devops and use the 'limit job authorization scope' and 'Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines' on organization level. but now we need some cross-project azure pipelines and as expected we get an authorization error when using the checkout task:

```
remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier SecondRepo does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.
fatal: repository 'https://dev.azure.com/myorg/SecondProject/_git/SecondRepo/' not found
##[warning]Git fetch failed with exit code 128, back off 1.451 seconds before retry
```

We thought we were smart and gave the 'FirstProject Build Service (myorg)' (which runs the pipeline) access to the SecondRepo repository. However, we still get the authorization error described above.
i would have expected that the limit job authorization settings would not automatically give the user more rights. but as it looks to us, manually set rights are probably also deliberately removed.

is this intended?

Comment: Hi @chrisblankde, please check my answer below, is Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines setting help solve the problem? If it helps, just a remind of [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to disable the **Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines** setting at project level and organization level for the project where you are running the pipeline. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#why-cant-i-check-out-a-repository-from-another-project-it-used-to-work).

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what i NOT want to do. we want to use the limited scope, but add just one other repo/team project by permission.